# AFNetworking - Download multiple files + monitoring via UIProgressView

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I am trying to change my code from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking. Currently I want to select 10-15 different HTTP URLs (files) and download them to a documents folder.

With ASIHTTPRequest that was pretty easy with

```
[myQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:myUIProgressView];
```

In AFNetworking I can't figure out how to do it. I have the following code which downloads the files, stores them and notifies when a file downloads successfully, but I can't create the progress bar for this queue with total size.

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {

    NSString *urlpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com/file.zip"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlpath]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"testFile%i.zip",i]];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes, %@", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, path);
    }];

    [myQueue addOperation:operation];  
}
```

Comment: Hi John, I would appreciate it if you would accept my answer if it works for you or if it is not answered for you please tell us what the issue is?

Comment: I think it is because you give a hint how to set the progress HUD for just one download, and what John wants is a progressbar for the whole queue.

Answer (score 12):

I think you will have to create your own UIProgressView, which I will call progressView for the example.

```
progressVu = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[progressVu setProgressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
```

Then just update the progress bar:

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    float percentDone = ((float)((int)totalBytesWritten) / (float)((int)totalBytesExpectedToWrite));

    progressView.progress = percentDone;

    NSLog(@"Sent %d of %d bytes, %@", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite, path);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

    float percentDone = ((float)((int)totalBytesRead) / (float)((int)totalBytesExpectedToRead));

    progressView.progress = percentDone;

}];
```

Comment: This code display error `Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSInteger, long long, long long)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSUInteger, long long, long long)'`

Answer (score 0):

Imagine downloading 200+ files this way by assuming a file size of 1 MB each. 
What happens when you create such a bunch of requests (with a default timeout of 30s)?
Right after 30 seconds you will be bombed by timeout errors.

Just sayin'
Martin